# Stuck on creating foreign key on android studio

Tags: android, sqlite, foreign-keys

Foreign key not working in Android. I have tried:

```
@Override
public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db) 
{
    super.onOpen(db);
    if (!db.isReadOnly()) {
        // Enable foreign key constraints
        //db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
        //(OR)
        db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled (true);
    }
}
```

This is how i have created the tables:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + 
    "(_id INTEGER PRIMARY AUTOINCREMENT,
    NAME TEXT, 
    SURNAME TEXT,
    MARKS INTEGER,
    SDATE TEXT )"
);

db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + 
    SCHOOL_TABLE_NAME +
    "(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    SCHOOL TEXT, 
    LOCATION TEXT, 
    S_id INTEGER, 
    FOREIGN KEY(S_id) REFERENCES" + TABLE_NAME + "(" + COL_1 + ")" )
);
```

Still no foreign key. What am i missing? Please help

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "not working"? What did you expect to happen, and what actually happened?

Comment: I was hoping i could see the foreign key using my SQLite Manager on firefox.. am such a newbie bear with me